# Unsupported mail transport [microsoft-graph] working in local, error in live

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-mail

I am facing an issue using **Microsoft Graph** as Mailer in my Laravel Application.
My code is working fine in my local environment; surprisingly, it's showing an error in the Live environment.

> InvalidArgumentException
> Unsupported mail transport [**microsoft-graph**].

PHP 8.1.18; Laravel 9.52.10
Hosted in: Godaddy Linux Server

Package using:

```
"innoge/laravel-msgraph-mail": "^1.0",
```

mail.php

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

'mailers' => [
    'microsoft-graph' => [
        'transport' => 'microsoft-graph',
        'client_id' => env('MICROSOFT_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('MICROSOFT_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'tenant_id' => env('MICROSOFT_GRAPH_TENANT_ID'),
        'from' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
        ],
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],
```

.env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER="microsoft-graph"
MICROSOFT_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID="graph-client-id"
MICROSOFT_GRAPH_TENANT_ID="tenant-id"
MICROSOFT_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET="K.someSecretHash"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="sales@myDomain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Me"
```

controller:

```
Mail::send('front.layouts.auth.password_reset', ['token' => $token], function ($message) 
    use ($request) {
        $message->to($request->email);
        $message->subject('Reset Password');
    });
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Are you sure the composer package is well installed in live environment ?

Comment: The package is installed in live environment via github action. I also did upload vendor folder of local project. Still same error

Comment: php artisan config:clear

Comment: I replaced the whole live project manually, and then it worked. There may be some issue in the GitHub action.